# Troubleshooting proxy issues

Tags: networking, proxy, http, https, socks

My IT is very unreliable in providing me support. My company has provided 2 proxies for reaching the internet. Let's call them proxy A & B. Proxy A supports HTTP, HTTPS, and SOCKS. Proxy B supports HTTP & HTTPS. I want to use proxy A. I am able to ping the proxy, resolve the proxy, but I simply cannot browse the internet through the same proxy. The reason why I mentioned about proxy B is that I am able to successfully browse to the internet through that, but I want to browse through Proxy A because of SOCKS. I am 100% not messing up the port numbers.

I have tried a variety of VMs, browsers, and OSes. This does not work.

The team has simply stated "turn don't use ipv6 address or add the name resolution for the proxy ato use ipv4 address instead"

I've unchecked IPv6 on the adapter settings, but I cannot understand what else to do. Can you please advise?

Comment: You can use a proxy for http and https, and a different one for socks

Comment: I know. Proxy A does not work for either http, https or socks.

Comment: (bumping this as no answers since 2 days)